# How can I implement such a map-like operation in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list and an arbitrary function taking 4 parameters, let's say `{1, 11, 3, 13, 9, 0, 12, 7}` and `f[{x,y,z,w}]={x+y, z+w}`, what I want to do is to form a new list such that 4 consecutive elements in the original list are evaluated to get a new value as the new list's component, and the evaluation has to be done in every 2 positions in the original list, in this case, the resulting list is:

```
{{12, 16}, {16, 9}, {9, 19}}
```

Note here 4 and 2 can change. How to do this conveniently in Mathematica? I imagine this as something like `Map`, but not sure how to relate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
f[{x_, y_, z_, w_}] = {x + y, z + w};
list = {1, 11, 3, 13, 9, 0, 12, 7};
f /@ Partition[list, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 14):

There's an alternative to `Map[f, Partition[...]]`: [`` Developer`PartitionMap ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html).  Which works exactly like `Map[f, Partition[list, n, ...]]`. So, your code would be

```
Needs["Developer`"]
f[{x_, y_, z_, w_}] = {x + y, z + w};
list = {1, 11, 3, 13, 9, 0, 12, 7};
PartitionMap[f,list, 4, 2]
```

giving the same result as [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774685/198315).